# Can maven plugin update project dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to update or add dependencies to project during initialization/compilation via maven plugin? I've tried ti my Mojo:

```
Dependency dep = new Dependency();
dep.setGroupId("example");
dep.setArtifactId("sample");
dep.setVersion("4.3");
dep.setScope("compile");
project.getModel().addDependency(dep);

getLog().info("Dependency count:" + project.getDependencies().size())
```

project obtained via `@Parameter` as `${project}`. But running sample project with this plugin with goals `validate dependency:tree` shows that plugin mojo was executed however dependency tree is empty - added dependency is lost. Is `project` just readable? I couldn't find any documentation about this so far.

I know you can update project dependencies in gradle like this via custom gradle plugin.

Comment: As already mentioned by J Fabian Meier the dependency resolution is done during start time of Maven. The other question is why do you like to do that ? And why kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are resolved at the beginning of the Maven run.

So when you run a plugin, dependencies have already been resolved.

The question that remains: What do you want to achieve with your approach? Which problem do you want to solve?